# Spring Boot Application - JSTL not working

Tags: spring-boot, jsp, tomcat, jstl

I'm pretty new to spring boot. I have created an application with spring boot but wanted it on a server. So I have added tomcats essentials to pom.xml. My application is basically CRUD application it just has a login page before the table is shown. Well, it successfully controls the database and logs in but it doesn't show the table the way I want it seems that my controller can't pass the list of users but when I run my application as a java application there is no such problem but as I run it on tomcat server it gets this problem. I have controlled if my controller gets the list of users in the controller and yes it does get it and it should pass it. Like I said before it must be true because as an application it worked perfectly but on the server, it acts differently.

**This is my Table.jsp where my table should be shown (the boxName and boxEmail has the same problem)**

```
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import = "java.sql.*"  import = "java.util.*"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"  %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>

      <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <!--<spring:url value="/resources/rehberStyle.css" var="rehberStyle" />
        <link href="${rehberStyle}" rel="stylesheet" />
        -->
         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link href="rehberStyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Rehber</title>
    </head>
    <body >
        <header >
            <h1 >Rehber</h1>
        </header>


        <div class="search-box">
            <form action="display" method="post" class="form" onsubmit="">
                <input class="search-txt" id="barName" name="searchBarName" placeholder="Name" formaction = "">
                <a href="#" class="search-btn" style="text-decoration: none;">
                    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                </a>
            </form>
        </div>
            <form action="addTransfer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn2" style="text-decoration: none;">Add New Data</button>
            </form>

            <form action="logout" method="post">
                <button  class="btn3" type="submit" >Logout</button>
            </form>
        <div class="divv">
            <form action="update" method="post">
                    <label class ="labels">Name</label>
                    <input  type="text" class="textBox" name="textName" id="textName" value="${boxName}" >
                    <label class ="labels">Email</label>
                    <input  type="text" class="textBox" name="textEmail" id = "textEmail" value="${boxEmail}" >
                    <button type="submit"  class="btn4" >Update</button>
            </form>
        </div>

            <table id="rehber" align="center"  >
                <thead>
                    <tr bgcolor="#333">
                        <th  style="width: 0%;"><font color="#fff">ID</font></th>
                        <th  style="width: 0%;"><font color="#fff">NAME</font></th>
                        <th  style="width: 0%;"><font color="#fff">EMAIL</font></th>
                        <th  style="width: 100%;"><font color="#fff">ACTION</font></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <TBody>
                    <c:forEach items="${listUser}" var="list">
                    <tr>
                        <td><input readonly name="id" id="id" value="<c:out value="${list.id}"/>"></td>
                        <td><input readonly name="name" id="name" value="<c:out value="${list.name}"/>"></td>
                        <td><input readonly name="email" id="email" value="<c:out value="${list.email}"/>"></td>
                        <td>
                            <form action="fill/${list.id}" method="post">
                                <input type="submit" style="text-decoration: none; background:#333;" class="edit" value ="Edit">
                            </form>
                            <form action="delete/${list.id}" method="post">
                                <input type="submit" style="text-decoration: none; background: rgb(163, 2, 2);" class="edit"value="Delete">
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </TBody>
            </table>
        <!-- </form>  -->
        <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {

            var nameArray = new Array();

            <c:forEach var="row" items="${listName}">
                nameArray.push('${row}');
            </c:forEach>
            $( function() {

                $( "#barName" ).autocomplete({
                  source: nameArray,
                  messages: {
                      noResults: '',
                      results: function(amount) {
                          return  ''
                      }
                  }
                });
              } );

        });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**This is where the controller method where i assign listUser**

```
@RequestMapping("/display")
    public String displayTable(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model, HttpSession session) { //buradana devam ettt

        List<User> list=new ArrayList<User>();
        ArrayList<String> name=new ArrayList<String>();
        String queryName = request.getParameter("searchBarName");

        if(valid.equals(true)) {
            if(queryName!=null && queryName.length()>0 ) {

                list=service.findName(queryName);
                //model.addAttribute("listUser", list);
                request.getSession().setAttribute("listUser", list);

            }else {

                list=service.listAll();
                for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
                    name.add(list.get(i).getName());
                }
                request.getSession().setAttribute("listName", name);
                request.getSession().setAttribute("listUser", list);

            }


            return "table";
        }

        return "index";

    }
```

**This is how it shows the table**

[image]

**But this is how i want it to be**

[image]

Comment: @BalusC it seems that you have closed my question but the problem is that it didn't resolve my issue. Like I said I'm using spring boot and i don't use web.xml at all I use SpringBootServletInitializer to my configurations.

Comment: @BalusC I don't know if you can see this but I solved my issue I have changed my pom.xml and my web modules version.